# Outlook Add-in Development : Detect If Mail Is Opened In Reading Pane Or Not

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have one add-in in ribbon.

This is not VSTO add-in.This is developed in C#.

I have implemented a functionality to enable/disable add-in control on change of mail selection.

What i am facing...

1. Open outlook
2. No mail selected
3. Outlook reading-pane shows 'Select an item to read'
4. Add-in is being enabled in this case
5. In this case, I want to disable my add-in control

[Outlook Reading Pane View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMC9z.png)

I want to detect below things :

- If mail is not opened in outlook reading-pane.
- If outlook reading-pane showing 'Select item to read'.

Thanks for answers in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If mail is not opened in outlook reading-pane.
> If outlook reading-pane showing 'Select item to read'.

In both cases the [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection) property returns a `Selection` object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window.

The `Selection` property does not include any conversation header objects. Call the `Selection.GetSelection` method, providing `olConversationHeaders` as the argument, to obtain conversation header objects that are selected in the explorer.

If the current folder displays a folder home page, this property returns an empty collection. Also, if a group header such as `Today`, or a conversation group header is selected, the `Count` property on the returned `Selection` object is zero.

Also if you want to know whether a reading pane is visible in Outlook you need to use the [Explorer.IsPaneVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Explorer.IsPaneVisible) method which returns a boolean indicating whether a specific explorer pane is visible.